# Karma not starting phantomJs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, phantomjs, gulp, karma-runner

I'm loosing my mind here. I have a gulp task that looks like this.

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var karma = require("karma").server;

gulp.task("test", function (done) {
    karma.start({
        configFile: __dirname + "/karma.conf.js",
        action:"run"
    }, function () {
        done();
    });
});
```

My karma.conf.js looks like this:

```
    module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],
        files: [
            "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js",
            "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-resource.min.js",
            "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.13.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js",
            "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.14/angular-ui-router.min.js",
            "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular-mocks.js",
            "src/js/**/*.js",
            "test/**/*.js"
        ],
        browser: ["PhantomJS"],
        singleRun: true
    });
};
```

However when I run `gulp test` all I get is this:[image]

And no browser starts.And the tests won't run. When looking at other examples at this point it should start Phantomjs.. I specified PhantomJs as the browser in the config-file. It doesn't help to change browser either.. How to I get karma to launch the browser?

I'm not sure if it is a super basic step I'm missing. I can't find anything on this when googling.
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: try changing browser property to `browser: ["chrome"]` and then test if it is working with chrome or not. are you getting any error in console?

Comment: if i go to `localhost:9876` in a browser (eg chrome) the tests are run. But changing to chrome in the config file does nothing. I want karma to launch the browser, preferrably phantomjs

Comment: I have no errors in the console

Comment: try to run karma using this command `karma start karma.conf.js --log-level debug --single-run`. if its working fine with this then config file is ok.

Comment: Same issue: Karma server starts but no browser is launched. In the console it prints all the resolved files from the `files`-property

Comment: Do you have karma-phantomjs-launcher

Installed

Comment: Just installed it and added it to the `plugins` -property in the config-file. Still nothing...

Comment: Is it something missing in the gulp task? Do i need something extra in the object provided to the `karma.start`-function?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78345/discussion-between-jad-panda-and-gustav).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The documentations](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/browsers.html) says

> Capturing browsers on your own can be a tedious and time consuming task, so Karma can automate this for you. Simply add the browsers you would like to capture into the configuration file:
>
> ```
> browsers: ['Chrome']
> ```

Note the name of the property: it's `browsers`, not `browser`.

Comment: We've all been there :)